# Modifying unordered_map in loop

Tags: c++, unordered-map

This is a pretty simple unordered map question, but I haven't found an explicit answer. If I have some unordered map, say

```
unordered_map<int, double> aggregateCollisions
```

and I want to multiply the value associated with every key by some constant double, say C, does the following do this?

```
for(auto pair : aggregateCollisions)
{
    pair.second *= C;
}
```

Comment: In this case `pair` is a copy of the value, change that for `auto& pair`.

Comment: What happens when you try? The compiler won't bite you :)

Comment: Haha good point @DougT. I was so wrapped up in a big project I didn't think to make a little test code. From an efficiency standpoint then, if I don't need a copy would it be more efficient to generally use a reference, or is this trivial?

Comment: It is not a matter of efficiency here. If you need to modify the contained value, you must use a reference to it.

Comment: @Chnossos I meant in a separate case, suppose I do not need to modify the value, e.g. I am reading it to a .csv file. In that case would it make sense to use a const reference? I had my code making copies every time, and I realize that's not always the way to do it.

Comment: Use `const auto &` unless you actually need a copy or the type is small (like an `int`).